# Postgres: using table_to_xmlschema on a table with a Box element

Tags: xml, postgresql, jaxb, xsd

So, I'm trying to extract an XML description of my Postgres database tables that I can use with JAXB to handle some Java<->DB communication.  The problem is, I'm using the Postgres 'box' datatype for several fields in my tables, and the Postgres table_to_xmlschema doesn't appear to generate valid XML for boxes.

Here's my SSCCE:

Postgres table creation: `create table BoxTest ( foo Box);`

Postgres call to generate an XML schema: `select * from table_to_xmlschema('BoxTest', true, true, 'SomeName');`

Resulting schema:

```
<xsd:schema
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     targetNamespace="SomeName"
     elementFormDefault="qualified">
 <xsd:simpleType name="UDT.User.pg_catalog.box">
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:complexType name="RowType.User.public.boxtest">
   <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="foo" type="UDT.User.pg_catalog.box" nillable="true"></xsd:element>
   </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:element name="boxtest" type="RowType.User.public.boxtest"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

The problem is that the description for the 'box' type is empty, despite that being a built-in type of Postgres.  (In particular, I get a SAX parsing error, with the message `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: s4s-elt-must-match.2: The content of 'simpleType' must match (annotation?, (restriction | list | union)). Not enough elements were found.`)  So - is there some option I should be passing/setting to correct that output?  If there isn't a built-in option, is there an easy way within Postgres to tweak/correct the output of table_to_xmlschema?  And with any proposed solution - what will I have to do to make JAXB work correctly with the resulting schema?

If it matters, I'm using Postgres 9.1, and (I think) jaxb-impl 2.1.6.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PostgreSQL version? My Pg doesn't have `table_to_xmlschema(regclass,boolean,boolean,boolean)` it has `table_to_xmlschema(regclass,boolean,boolean,text)`. You seem to be on something ancient like 8.2 and are being bitten by an implicit cast to text - notice `targetNamespace="false"` in your output. Update urgently, 8.2 is leaving support soon.

Comment: What specifically does JAXB complain about? Exact error message please? What's the *expected* output? If you set the `tableforest` argument (3rd arg, 2nd boolean) to `false` does it produce what you want?

Comment: Edited the question as appropriate - Postgres 9.1; I was indeed getting an implicit cast for the namespace.  I'd like the definition for the "box" type to indicate the box's actual contents - e.g. a pair of x,y coordinates that define a region on a plane.  Changing the parameters of the call to table_to_xmlschema doesn't affect the generation of an empty simpleType entry for the box field.

Comment: Ah, so your issue is that composite types' structures aren't included (possibly recursively) in the schema, but are instead referenced as `UDT.....` . Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

As Craig notes, the current `table_to_xmlschema` function does not recursively decompose recursive types.  I don't see this changing in the near future, and certainly not in stable versions so your best option is to write your own function which looks at the catalogs, and recursively builds a schema for you.  This shouldn't be too bad but it will be a bit of work.  I am actually working on similar projects for complex data presentation between PostgreSQL and the application though not using XML as an intermediary.  The actual queries needed to do this are not too bad.

What you will need to do is create a recursive query to look up types, (a WITH RECURSIVE cte on pg_attribute and pg_type) and then a function, possibly in pl/perl or the like, which generates the appropriate text for you.

The built-in functions will not work for you though.